# NestJS Telegraf - Webhook(s) for multiple telegram bots

Tags: node.js, nestjs, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf

Setting up a webhook for a single bot seems to work, but once I add another one I'm starting to get an error:

`Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::80`

Here's how I'm settting up the TelegrafModule for each bot:

```
TelegrafModule.forRootAsync({
          botName: 'bot-name1'
          useFactory: () => ({
            token: 'bot-token1'
            launchOptions: {
              webhook: {
                port: 80,
                domain: 'my-domain'
                hookPath: '/bot-username1',
              },
            },
            include: [TelegramBotModule],
          })

TelegrafModule.forRootAsync({
          botName: 'bot-name2'
          useFactory: () => ({
            token: 'bot-token2'
            launchOptions: {
              webhook: {
                port: 80,
                domain: 'my-domain'
                hookPath: '/bot-username2',
              },
            },
            include: [TelegramBotModule],
          })
```

And here's how I'm listening to the webhooks in main.ts:

```
const bot = app.get(getBotToken('bot-name1'));
const bot2 = app.get(getBotToken('bot-name2'));

app.use(bot.webhookCallback('/bot-username1'));
app.use(bot2.webhookCallback('/bot-username1'));
```

I've also tried using the same hook path for both bots, and got the same error. (/secret-path)